# How can I reference the output of the first command when chaining PowerShell commands

Tags: powershell, activesync

How can I extract one value from the first part of a command chain in my output? For example:

```
Get-ActiveSyncDevice | Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics | ft UserDeviceAgent,Identity -a
```

As a fictional example, assume the column UserDeviceAgent is visible in `Get-ActiveSyncDevice`, however I can't get it to appear in the final output

[image]

**Please note:**

My question is specifically: How do I "back reference" an output in the command chain?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass it down the pipe, so in your script you would have to convert the second portion of the pipe to a ForEach, and then output both the desired property, and the results of your second command.

So to take your hypothetical let's say this:

```
Get-ActiveSyncDevice | %{
    $CurDev = Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics
    add-member -InputObject $CurDev -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserDeviceAgent -Value $_.UserDeviceAgent
    $CurDev
}| ft    UserDeviceAgent, Identity -a
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `-OutVariable` on the first CmdLet and then run an expression in Format-Table at the end:

```
Get-ActiveSyncDevice -OutVariable ASD | `
Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics | `
Format-Table Identity, @{Name="UserDeviceAgent"; Expression ={$ASD.Item($ASD.Count-1).UserDeviceAgent}}
```